# Exchange Server Error

Tags: exchange-server

We are not able to resolve one exchange  error:

The below error occurred while trying to connect to the particular exchange server server.domain.local

The effort to connect to http://server.domain.local/PowerShell with the help of the Kerberos authentication failed:

Connecting to remote server failed “http server error status (500)”

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

IIS Manager | Default Website |PowerShell
Change the physical path
from: **C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\PowerShell**
to: **C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\ClientAccess\PowerShell**

After the change: IISRESET

If the same problem, still persists, then please perform the rebuilding of new Exchange server.

Hope it works.